# MySQL retrieving primary key from query SELECT DISTINCT

Tags: mysql

I have a simple question. I have the following mysql query:

`SELECT DISTINCT name FROM nametable WHERE status = 0 ORDER BY id ASC`

That will give me a table with all different names starting with the lowest id number to the largest. I want to process these names one by one and need to retrieve the id associated with the names, however, the query only returns the distinct names, how can I get the id's associated with the names. When I add the id in the query like this:

`SELECT DISTINCT id, name FROM nametable WHERE status = 0 ORDER BY id ASC`

of course, it will give me all the different id's which will give me duplicated names which is not want I want.

**UPDATE:**

So I just did the query and it turned out something like the following. Is, there a way to just get the first number of each the ID? I also noticed the IDs of the groupconcat are not in ASC order, I need to get the first ID starting from the lowest.

```
 ----------------------------
| name   | Group_Concat(ID)  |   
----------------------------
| name1  | 1,2,3,4           | //1
----------------------------- 
| name2  | 22,20             | //20
-----------------------------
| name3  | 12                | //12
-----------------------------
| name4  | 45, 41            | //41
----------------------------
| name5  | 55, 51, 52       |  //51
----------------------------
```

**Resolved with the following:**

`SELECT id, name FROM nametable WHERE status = 0 GROUP BY name ORDER BY id ASC`

Comment: This query seems a bit questionable. Consider this scenario: ("Joe", 1), ("Joe", 1000), ("Bob", 50).

Comment: @Uueerdo Yes, in your example, I want it to show only ("Joe", 1) and ("Bob", 50) being the 1 and 50 is the id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you are looking for:

```
SELECT MIN(id), name
    , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT id ORDER BY id) AS idList -- If you need them
FROM nametable
WHERE status = 0
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY MIN(id);
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably need something like

```
SELECT name,
         GROUP_CONCAT(id)
       FROM table
       GROUP BY name;
```

The source is MySQL [documentation:](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

> In MySQL, you can get the concatenated values of expression
>   combinations. To eliminate duplicate values, use the DISTINCT clause.
>   To sort values in the result, use the ORDER BY clause. To sort in
>   reverse order, add the DESC (descending) keyword to the name of the
>   column you are sorting by in the ORDER BY clause. The default is
>   ascending order; this may be specified explicitly using the ASC
>   keyword. The default separator between values in a group is comma (,).
>   To specify a separator explicitly, use SEPARATOR followed by the
>   string literal value that should be inserted between group values. To
>   eliminate the separator altogether, specify SEPARATOR ''.

I see you updated the question so to my understanding you always need the lowest id.

Then you need to use the [MIN()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) function.
This would look something like that:

```
SELECT name,
             MIN(id)
           FROM table
           GROUP BY name;
```

Comment: Thanks Battle_Slug, I updated my result above with another question. I was wondering if there is a way to just get the first ID of each name.

Comment: I also noticed the IDs of the groupconcat are not in ASC order, I need to get the first ID starting from the lowest ID, is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Never mind I think I figured it out with the following: `SELECT id, name FROM nametable WHERE status = 0 GROUP BY name ORDER BY id ASC`

Comment: @kkmoslehpour I would recommend against that; relying on non-aggregated fields to remain consistent (in a query they are not a part of the grouping criteria of) is just asking for trouble eventually; newer MySQL installations default their settings to not even allowing such queries.

Comment: Ah okay, good to know thank you! One last thing that is missing is I want to Order By MIN(id) so smallest id is on the top then it will complete my query.